# Java code to validate JSON object against mongo query

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I need to write a simple Java code to compare JSON record against mongo query language

- The main function is to get the JSON record that matches with the mongo query

Example:

From https://querybuilder.js.org/demo.html

MongoDB Query:

---

[Mongo query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g8bi.png)

Mongo code for the above query

```
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "name": {
        "$regex": "^Test"
      }
    },
    {
      "in_stock": 1
    },
    {
      "price": {
        "$lt": 1000
      }
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "category": 6
        },
        {
          "category": 2
        },
        {
          "category": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Incoming JSON records

Record1
{name : “Test”, in_stock : 1, price : 100, category : 2}

Record2
{name : “Test”, in_stock : 0, price : 100, category : 2}

Record3
{name : “Test”, in_stock : 1, price : 100, category : 6}

Record4
{name : “Test”, in_stock : 1, price : 100, category : 2, age : 22}

---

According to the above records. Only Record1 will match the criteria

There is implementation already for this request but using nodeJS

https://github.com/kofrasa/mingo

Just to summarize.

Java code or API to receive JSON object that could have any format. It will be checked against mongo query like the one shared above.  I need to check if the JSON record satisfies the mongo query

Comment: Can you show your attempt so far in Java?

Comment: Hi Bajal. I only tried the nodeJS code and its working fine. https://github.com/kofrasa/mingo ... I need some guidance before i work the java version.